# Why Is My Picture Thumbnail Not Showing

Tags: finder

when I dragged a folder to ⌘I (info) it displayed [image: a picture icon instead of the actual picture? Any help? the clear preferences doesn't work]

Answer (score 1):

Does the image open and appear in Preview.app? If not, the Finder will also not be able to open and create a thumbnail.

## Show Icon Preview

Assuming the file is a valid image and does open in Preview.app, make sure **Show icon preview** is enabled for the Finder's view:

1. Select the file in the Finder
2. Select **Finder > View (menu) > Show View Options**
3. Enable the **Show icon preview** checkbox:

[image: Show View Options]